# Laravel Eloquent Relationship has the same foreign key on the same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm a beginner in Laravel and currently trying to create a ticketing system. My `tickets` table has two columns which both reference `id` from the `users` table namely `user_id` and `handled_by`. I am trying to eager load the `full_name` of `handled_by` but it is throwing an error "Trying to get property 'full_name' of non-object". I would like to know how to properly create an eloquent relationship between `handled_by` and `tickets` so I could display the `handled_by`'s `full_name`. Below are snippets of my code.

User Model:

```
 public function tickets(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Ticket');
    }

 public function handledBy(){
      return $this->hasMany('\App\User', 'handled_by', 'id');
  }
```

Ticket Model:

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');
}
public function handledBy(){
  return $this->belongsTo('\App\User', 'handled_by', 'id');
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($tickets as $ticket)
<td class="align-middle text-center">{{ $ticket->handled_by->full_name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
$tickets = Ticket::all()->where('status_id', '1');
return view('admin.open_tickets', compact('tickets'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User model, change `\App\User` to `\App\Ticket`, and change the method name from `handlerBy` to `handlers`:

```php
public function handlers(){
      return $this->hasMany('\App\Ticket', 'handled_by', 'id');
}
```

And call it by method's name instead of underline case name:

```php
{{ $ticket->handledBy->full_name}}
```

Comment: Hi TsaiKoga, thank you for the quick response, I tried the code but it still throws the same error.

Comment: @cjdy13 You need to call it by method name, not underline case name.

Comment: Thank you for the further clarifications, the code now works!